# Where in the standard to I read or deduce that vector<T>::operator[] invokes UB for out-of-bound input?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, indexoutofboundsexception, undefined-behavior, std

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/), I read the following about [`std::vector<T,Allocator>::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at):

> Accessing a nonexistent element through this operator is undefined behavior.

Does [the standard draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/) contain a similar sentence? Or, what part of the standard should I deduce this thing from?

I guess that if the standard says nothing about it, that would make it UB. But I haven't found anything about [`std::vector<T,Allocator>::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) either, so...

Comment: Regarding the `at` function, the reference says it "[r]eturns a reference to the element at specified location `pos`, **with bounds checking**" (emphasis mine). If the specification doesn't say anything about the `[]` operator, it should definitely mention the bounds-checking behavior of `at`, but maybe in different terms.

Comment: The standard doesn't work like that. Basically, it defines behavior only for programs that meet its rules and requirements. Programs that violate these rules have undefined behavior, but the standard does not need to explicitly say that (it says that in some cases).

Comment: The standard defines `v[i]` as equivalent to `*(v.begin()+i)` so the reasoning would require reading the sections on valid and dereferenceable iterators,

Comment: For `at()`, the standard explicitly defines behavior for out-of-bound input: http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#123.

Comment: @DanielLangr, oh, there it is. So the lack of that sentence a few lines above for `a[n]` makes it UB. That answers my question :)

Answer (score 5):

It's specified in a **very** roundabout way.

First, the members aren't specified for `vector` directly, but instead for the general `Sequence`. You can find the specification here: http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts.

First, the obvious part: `at` has the [clause](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#123)

> *Throws:* `out_of_range` if `n >= a.size()`.

So this is where `at`'s behavior comes from.

As for `[]`, it says:

> *Returns:* `*(a.begin() + n)`

So the effect is the same as of that expression. We need to follow this to find the undefined behavior. For that we need to look at the [iterator requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements).

Now the C++20 requirements are nigh-unreadable, but the C++17 requirements are still there and do apply. So:

- http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#random.access.iterators-1 says that `a + n` (for some iterator `a` and a difference `n`) means doing `tmp += n` for a copy `tmp` of `a`.
- Same place says that `r += n` means repeated applications of `++r` (or `--r` if `n` is negative).
- In http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#tab:inputiterator we learn that `++r` and `*a` both have the precondition that `r` or `a` respectively are *dereferenceable*. Note that violating a precondition means undefined behavior in C++ standardese.

This is where it gets really complicated. At this point we need to piece together the specifications of `vector::begin` and `vector::end` to understand that repeated incrementing of `v.begin()` will eventually (as in, after `v.size()` applications) yield `v.end()`, which is specified to be the *past-the-end* iterator. I cannot find the explicit statement that such iterators are *not* dereferenceable, but http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#general-7 specifies that the standard library assumes they are not, and in vector's case this is true.

Therefore, `v[v.size()]` is equivalent to `*(v.begin() + v.size())`, which is equivalent to `*v.end()`, which is undefined behavior.

And `v[v.size()+1]` is equivalent to `*(v.begin() + v.size() + 1)`, which is equivalent to `*std::next(v.end())`, which is incrementing the *past-the-end* iterator and thus undefined behavior.

Comment: I see the clause that `.at(n)` throws for `n` too large. But nothing if `n<0`?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout `n` is unsigned: http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#3.9 and http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#container.reqmts-9.

Comment: I'm guessing that makes `.at(-1)` UB because conversion?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout No, the conversion is well-defined, but the result is the maximum of `size_type` which will be `>=size()` and so it will throw.

Answer (score 1):

First note that `v[n]` is equivalent to `*(v.begin() + n)` as per [sequence.reqmts](https://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#119).

Now, if the iterator is not within the range, it is not derefereceble meaning `v[n]` is undefined behavior as per [iterator.requirements.general](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterator.requirements.general#7):

> Values of an iterator i for which the expression *i is defined are called **dereferenceable**. ***The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable.***